# Can't start nor remove MySQL

Tags: 16.04, 15.04, mysql

I was using MySQL without any error on Ubuntu 15.04.But yesterday I upgraded to 16.04LTS from 15.04 yesterday(15.04 to 15.10 and 15.10 to 16.04LTS).
I'm having some issues now

When I check MySQL status using

```
mysqladmin -u root -p status
```

I'm getting this error

```
 mysqladmin: Can't read dir of '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
 mysqladmin: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

So I tried remove it using

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
```

And I'm getting this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbconfig-mysql : Depends: mysql-client but it is not going to be installed or
                       mariadb-client but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtual-mysql-client
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

As I'm a new to Ubuntu can anyone help me with the situation ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me this looks like a dependency issue, so you can try this:

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get remove --purge mysql*
apt-get autoclean
deluser mysql
rm -rf /var/log/mysql
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect answer!